# How to find sum of qty for each month from the table that keep qty in dozen and piece at the same time?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm working on plotting graph to show sum of qty that each product had been placed for each month. But since my table was keep qty some in "dozen" and some in "piece", and I don't know how to make this sum on SQL. So could you please kindly help me. Thank you very much.

below is my table and data samples...

```
tbl_order
od_id | pd_id | od_qty | od_qty_unit | showndate
  01  |  01   |   1    |  dz         |   12/6/12
  02  |  01   |   1    |  pcs        |   13/6/12
  03  |  01   |   2    |  dz         |   15/6/12
  04  |  02   |   3    |  dz         |   15/6/12
  05  |  03   |   10   |  pcs        |   18/6/12
  06  |  01   |   3    |  dz         |   1/8/12
```

the result that I want should be sum of qty from "June" month only

```
pd_id | od_qty
  01  |  37
  02  |  36
  03  |  10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MS Access SQL, use IIF:

```
SELECT tbl_order.pd_id, 
       Sum(IIf([od_qty_unit]='dz',[od_qty]*12,[od_qty])) AS Qty
FROM tbl_order
GROUP BY tbl_order.pd_id;
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This is very helpful for me who has knowledge of sql so limit.

Answer (score 0):

I dont do much work in MS-Access but this is how I would solve it on MSSQL. As far as I know the syntax is very similar (some keywords that exists in MSSQL are missing from access), so I hope it works for you. If nothing else it might give you a clue as to how you can solve it.

The general idea is that you want to create a column containing the "real" quantity of items. To do this I use a CASE switch where depending on the unit I can multiply the number by the required multiple.. ie. 1 dozen is 1 * 12 items.

```
DECLARE @data TABLE
(
    od_id int,
    pd_id int,
    od_qty int,
    od_qty_unit NVARCHAR(3),
    showndate DATE
)

INSERT INTO @data VALUES(1,1,1,'dz', '2012-06-12')
INSERT INTO @data VALUES(2,1,1,'pcs', '2012-06-13')
INSERT INTO @data VALUES(3,1,2,'dz', '2012-06-15')
INSERT INTO @data VALUES(4,2,3,'dz', '2012-06-15')
INSERT INTO @data VALUES(5,3,10,'pcs', '2012-06-18')
INSERT INTO @data VALUES(6,1,3,'dz', '2012-08-1')


SELECT 
    pd_id, 
    SUM(d.RealQuantity) 
FROM 
    (
        SELECT 
            pd_id,
            od_qty,
            od_qty_unit,
            CASE 
                WHEN od_qty_unit = 'pcs' THEN od_qty
                WHEN od_qty_unit = 'dz' THEN od_qty * 12
            END AS RealQuantity
        FROM @data 
        WHERE
            MONTH(showndate) = 6
            AND YEAR(showndate) = 2012
    ) AS d
GROUP by pd_id
```

The code returns this result:

[image]

Comment: The case statement exists in ms Access too, you should be able to create somethin close to this. http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/advanced/case.php

Comment: VBA is not the same as Jet/ACE sql.